# How to sum values with same array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I merged two arrays (both fetched from mysql which are in different tables) and now I want to sum all with the same value in the array.

`$merged_arr = array_merge($reg, $rel);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DEPARTMENT] => LEAFSPRINGDIRECT
            [BASIC INCOME] => 3035.37
            [OT PAY] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DEPARTMENT] => MUFFLERDIRECT
            [BASIC INCOME] => 24962.09
            [OT PAY] => 5358.76
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DEPARTMENT] => MUFFLERDIRECT 
            [BASIC INCOME] => 14082.080000000002
            [OT PAY] => 3248.4
        )
)
```

This is what I have tried but I have to make if-else over and over again.

```
foreach($merged_arr as $key => $val) 
    {
        // echo $val['BASIC INCOME']."<br>";

        // echo array_keys(array_values($new_arr)[$key])[$count]."-".array_values(array_values($new_arr)[$key])[$count]."<br>";
        if(array_values(array_values($new_arr)[$key])[$count] == "RADIATORDIRECT") {
            $new_arr['BASIC INCOME'] += '...';
        }

        $count++;
    }
```

My desired array will be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DEPARTMENT] => LEAFSPRINGDIRECT
            [BASIC INCOME] => 3035.37
            [OT PAY] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DEPARTMENT] => MUFFLERDIRECT
            [BASIC INCOME] => 39044.17‬
            [OT PAY] => 8607.16‬
        )
)
```

How can I do it easier? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `MUFFLERDIRECT` and `MUFFLERINDIRECT` added together to the same one? They are not different departments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it on the SQL side like this:

```sql
SELECT DEPARTMENT, SUM(`BASIC INCOME`) AS `BASIC INCOME`,  SUM(`OT PAY`) AS `OT PAY`
FROM
(
    SELECT DEPARTMENT, `BASIC INCOME`, `OT PAY`
    FROM `table_a`
    -- WHERE ...

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DEPARTMENT, `BASIC INCOME`, `OT PAY`
    FROM `table_b`
    -- WHERE ...
    
) UNIONS

GROUP BY DEPARTMENT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//group by DEPARTMENT key
$groupedData = [];
foreach ($mergedData as $data) {
    $groupedData[$data['DEPARTMENT']][] = $data;
}

//sum over DEPARTMENT
$summedData = [];
foreach ($groupedData as $department => $departmentData) {
    $summedData[] = [
        'DEPARTMENT' => $department,
        'BASIC INCOME' => array_sum(array_column($departmentData, 'BASIC INCOME')),
        'OT PAY' => array_sum(array_column($departmentData, 'OT PAY'))
    ];
}
```

Test:

```
$mergedData = [
    ['DEPARTMENT' => 'LEAFSPRINGDIRECT', 'BASIC INCOME' => 3035.37, 'OT PAY' => 0],
    ['DEPARTMENT' => 'MUFFLERDIRECT', 'BASIC INCOME' => 24962.09, 'OT PAY' => 5358.76],
    ['DEPARTMENT' => 'MUFFLERDIRECT', 'BASIC INCOME' => 14082.080000000002, 'OT PAY' => 3248.4]
];


//group by DEPARTMENT key
$groupedData = [];
foreach ($mergedData as $data) {
    $groupedData[$data['DEPARTMENT']][] = $data;
}

//sum over DEPARTMENT
$summedData = [];
foreach ($groupedData as $department => $departmentData) {
    $summedData[] = [
        'DEPARTMENT' => $department,
        'BASIC INCOME' => array_sum(array_column($departmentData, 'BASIC INCOME')),
        'OT PAY' => array_sum(array_column($departmentData, 'OT PAY'))
    ];
}

var_dump($summedData);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DEPARTMENT"]=>
    string(16) "LEAFSPRINGDIRECT"
    ["BASIC INCOME"]=>
    float(3035.37)
    ["OT PAY"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DEPARTMENT"]=>
    string(13) "MUFFLERDIRECT"
    ["BASIC INCOME"]=>
    float(39044.17)
    ["OT PAY"]=>
    float(8607.16)
  }
}
```